# How to improve performance of point cloud viewer

Tags: c#, xna

I would like to create a simple point cloud viewer. Im using C# and XNA.
On this moment i've created this:

[image: Link]

I can rotate and zoom to it but perfomance is weak. On cloud with 1,500 000 points it takes approximately 6 seconds to complete rotate or zoom. Any ideas how to make it better?. Is there a possibility to rotate or zoom without redrawing everything?

My Code Snippet about drawing. Im using SpriteBatches:

```
ba.Begin();
for (int i = 0; i < DBmanager.data.Length; i++) 
{
    Vector3 screenLocation = Device.Viewport.Project(DBmanager.data[i], basicEffect.Projection, basicEffect.View, basicEffect.World);
    ba.Draw(pixel, new Vector2(screenLocation.X, screenLocation.Y), Color.Orange);
}
ba.End();
```

Move function:

```
private void move(float x,float y)
{
    //currentx += x;
    Debug.WriteLine(x);
    Debug.WriteLine(y);
    if (x == 0)
    {
        Vector3 target = new Vector3(Center.X, Center.Y, Center.Z);
        cameraPosition = Vector3.Transform(cameraPosition - target, Matrix.CreateRotationY(y)) + target;
        basicEffect.View = Matrix.CreateLookAt(cameraPosition, target, Vector3.Up);
    }
    if (y == 0)
    {
        Vector3 target = new Vector3(Center.X, Center.Y, Center.Z);
        cameraPosition = Vector3.Transform(cameraPosition - target, Matrix.CreateRotationX(x)) + target;
        basicEffect.View = Matrix.CreateLookAt(cameraPosition, target, Vector3.Up);
    }
}
```

My Draw Function:

```
        protected override void Draw()
    {
        if (called)
        {
            Application.Idle -= IdleHandler;
            timer.Stop();
            SetUpVertices();
            called = false;
            //Invalidate();
        }
       // if (drawn)
       // {
            //Application.Idle -= IdleHandler;
            //timer.Stop();
           //  UpdateCam();
          //  Debug.WriteLine("Obrót zakonczony");
            //SetUpVertices();
       // }
        if (leftDrag)
        {
            Application.Idle -= IdleHandler;
            timer.Stop();
            UpdateCam();
            //SetUpVertices();
            leftDrag = false;
        }
        if (Zoomed)
        {
            Application.Idle -= IdleHandler;
            timer.Stop();
            Zoom(Zoomlevel);
            //UpdateCam();
            //SetUpVertices();
            Zoomed = false;
        }

    }
```

SetupVertices:

```
    private void SetUpVertices()
    {
        Device.Clear(Color.Black);
        VertexPositionColor [] Verts = new VertexPositionColor [65535];
        RasterizerState rasterizerState = new RasterizerState();
        rasterizerState.CullMode = CullMode.None;
        Device.RasterizerState = rasterizerState;
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < DBmanager.data.Length; i++)
        {
            if (j==65535)
            {
                buf = new VertexBuffer(Device, typeof(VertexPositionColor), Verts.Length, BufferUsage.WriteOnly);
                buf.SetData<VertexPositionColor>(Verts);
                Device.SetVertexBuffer(buf);
                foreach (EffectPass pass in basicEffect.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
                {
                    pass.Apply();
                    Device.DrawPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, 0, Verts.Length);
                }
                Verts = new VertexPositionColor[65535];
                j = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                Verts[j] = new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(DBmanager.data[i].X, DBmanager.data[i].Y, DBmanager.data[i].Z),Color.Orange);
                j++;
            }
        }
        if (!IsCenterCalculated)
        {
            Box = BoundingBox.CreateFromPoints(DBmanager.data);
            corners = Box.GetCorners();
            setCenter(CalculateCenter(corners));
            IsCenterCalculated = true;
            basicEffect.View = Matrix.CreateLookAt(cameraPosition, new Vector3(Center.X, Center.Y, Center.Z), Vector3.Up);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should separate interaction (`Game.Update()`), data management, and actual drawing (`Game.Draw()`). It appears that you draw the point cloud via `SetupVertices()`. Since this will also always send the whole data to the GPU again, you have the same problem as before. Set the vertices up only once and then you can `DrawPrimitives()` every frame. Btw, shouldn`t it be a `PointList` instead of `TriangleList`?

Comment: You shouldn't be calling `basicEffect.View` during setup either

Comment: Sprite batches are slow, that's essentially _immediate mode_ where all drawing operations are resent to the GPU each frame.  You want a technique where much is stored on the GPU persisted

Comment: @NicoSchertler xna 4.0 hasnt got pointlist. And after nest in winforms i cant use update. Everything goes on in Draw method.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do this is to use vertex buffers to store the point data. You upload them once to the graphics card and then just modify the view matrix.

This will avoid the upload of data in every frame and the graphics card performs the projection in parallel. With a minimal estimate of the data size of about 24 bytes per point, you get about 36 MB of data. If you upload this in every frame at 60 fps, you would require a transfer rate of about 16 Gb/s for the plain point data. And with the sprite batch, it is even more because you need to upload rectangles instead of points.

So just get familiar with vertex buffers. Put the data in once, upload them to the GPU. Then you can draw all points at once with a single draw call.

Comment: I tried your solution but is still the same.When I do rotate or zoom without redrawing all stuff,  Docked form turns blank. Maybe I misunderstood something. I can post my whole solution and you can told me what I doing wrong.

Comment: It should be no problem to draw everything when rotating. Just show your draw code (without the initialization stuff). This should be enough to judge what you are doing.